# jQuery $el.position(...) is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a nav bar which uses another `<li>` element in the list to create an underline effect that animates underneath the hovered element and animates back to the active element on mouse out.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jP59W/

It seems to work great in Chrome and Firefox but in IE (8) I get an `invalid argument error` but I can't see what could be causing it.

Even though it works in Firefox, it still throws this error aswell:

`$el.position(...) is undefined` which is this line:

```
leftPos = $el.position().left;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="active">
            <a id="myoeHome" href="#">Welcome</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="myAccount" href="#">Your Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="referAFriend" href="#">Refer A Friend </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a id="referralReport" href="#">View Rewards </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="shoutandShare" href="#">Write a Review </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 990px;
    margin: -21px 0 0 0;

    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    height: 35px;

    zoom: 1;
}

#navbar ul {
    width: 945px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top:-13px;

    *margin: -25px auto 0 auto;
}

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;

    /* padding: 0 1px 0 1px; */

    /* margin: 0 60px 0 5px; */

    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 24px 0;
    width: 185px;

    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
     *margin: 25px -11px 0 0;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #002e55;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 24px;

    *display: inline;
    *float: left;

 }

#magic-line {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: url("http://www.4playtheband.co.uk/assets/nav-magic-line.png") no-repeat center bottom;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;

    *bottom: 7px;
    *z-index: 999;
    *height: auto;
 }

#navbar ul li a:hover {
     height: 4px;
     /*border-bottom: 3px solid #002e55;*/

     zoom: 1;

    *margin-top: -39px;

}

#navbar ul li a.active {
    background: url("../images/psd/active-nav-bg.png") no-repeat 49% 2px;
    height: 4px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #002e55;

    zoom: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// nav
var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
$mainNav = $("#navbar ul");

$mainNav.prepend("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

function navBar() {
    // console.log('navBar start');
    function checkActive() {
        // console.log('check active');
        // Hide magic line if nav bar has no active element
        if($('#navbar ul').children('.active').length < 1) {
            $magicLine.hide();
            //console.log($('#navbar ul').children('.active').length < 1);
            //console.log($('#magic-line'));
            //console.log('hide');
        }
        else {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.css('left', $(".active a").css('left')),
                width: $magicLine.width($(".active a").width())
            });
        }
    }
    checkActive();
    $magicLine
        .width($(".active a").width())
        .css("left", $(".active a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $(".active a").width());

    // $("#navbar ul li a").hover(function() {
    // apply hover function to li instead and just just el to it's child
    $("#navbar ul li").hover(function() {
        // $el = $(this);
        $el = $(this).children('a');
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        }, 600);
    }, function() {
        if($('#navbar ul').children('.active').length < 1) {
            $magicLine.stop();
            checkActive();
        } else {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                //width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                width: $magicLine.width($(".active a").width())
            }, 600);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $magicLine.width($(".active a").width());
    navBar();
});
```

Comment: This does nothing for me - I see no animation of any type: Firefox 19.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. Firebug reports this error: `TypeError: $el.position(...) is undefined`

Comment: thanks, is it the fiddle you tried or did you implement the code on a test script? Fiddle works for me in chrome but the site itself doesn't seem to want to load in ie for me. Will check error in firefox but that's a great help to actually know what's going on, probably should've tried ff before ie for error testing.

Comment: I only tried the fiddle. I also just now tried the fiddle using Chrome (again, on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop) and I see no animation. I changed the fiddle to use the code you have in your answer and there was still no animation of any kind.

Comment: @BennyHill hmm strange. Thanks for your help anyway, just relieved I got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

Changed

```
leftPos = $el.position().left;
```

to

```
leftPos = $el.parent().position().left;
```

and that solved it.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen two cases when such a problem happens:

1. the item you are checking is currently hidden (was never shown) or is not in the document DOM and thus has no real coordinates (you can create DOM fragments)
2. the jQuery object (`$el` list in your case) is empty; you can know by testing `$el.length == 0`

Since the `parent()` call worked for you, your problem was most certainly case (1).

Comment: When I hide an element from the DOM and then use `$el.position()` I still get the values with `{top: 0, left: 0}` and not undefined as you write. The question is how to check if there is a position() or not.

Comment: @Avatar That was in 2016... Maybe jQuery was fixed since then, which would be great.