# jQuery - Why Doesn't IE8 Like This Function?

Tags: jquery

A brief overview of my site structure:

Main index php which serves up locally stored php files via ajax. (if it sounds messy, that's because it is)

I have a function in the main index file that I call from the ajax loaded scripts and it works fine everywhere except IE.

I can't get a meaningful error message:

```
Invalid argument.  jquery-1.4.2.min.js, line 144 character 219
```

N.B This question is directly related to my previous one: [jQuery $el.position(...) is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113145/jquery-el-position-is-undefined)

**jQuery Function (index.php)**

```
// nav
var $el;
var leftPos;
var newWidth;
var $mainNav = $("#navbar ul");

$mainNav.prepend("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

function navBar() {

    // console.log('navBar start');
    function checkActive() {
        // console.log('check active');
        // Hide magic line if nav bar has no active element
        if($('#navbar ul').children('.active').length < 1) {
            $magicLine.hide();
            //console.log($('#navbar ul').children('.active').length < 1);
            //console.log($('#magic-line'));
            //console.log('hide');
        }
        else {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.css('left', $(".active a").css('left')),
                width: $magicLine.width($(".active a").width())
            });
        }
    }
    checkActive();
    $magicLine
        .width($(".active a").width())
        .css("left", $(".active a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $(".active a").width());

    // $("#navbar ul li a").hover(function() {
    // apply hover function to li instead and just just el to it's child
    $("#navbar ul li").hover(function() {
        // $el = $(this);
        $el = $(this).children('a');
        // leftPos = $el.position().left;
        leftPos = $el.parent().position().left;
        newWidth = $el.width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        }, 600);
    }, function() {
        if($('#navbar ul').children('.active').length < 1) {
            $magicLine.stop();
            checkActive();
        } else {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                //width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                width: $magicLine.width($(".active a").width())
            }, 600);
        }
    });
}
```

This is called in all of my scripts by simply doing:

```
navBar();
```

but for some reason, it is causing issues in IE and I can't see any reason as to why it would.

Comment: Use chrome or firebug to get the stacktrace and see where it fails

Comment: thanks, but that's the thing, in Chrome and Firefox there are no errors reported so it's just IE.

Comment: Sorry, thinking on the problem forgot about details of the question in the process. Forgot what I said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just taking a stab here, but I would review this:

```
width: $magicLine.width($(".active a").width())
```

That's in an object being passed into `.animate()`. What that line is doing is setting the width of `$magicLine` to the `.active a` width, using jQuery's `.width()` function. What that function returns is a reference to the jQuery element you started with, `$magicLine`. This technique is what allows you to chain jQuery functions one after the other.

So, the line above would effectively resolve to:

```
width: $magicLine
```

What I believe you want is:

```
width: $(".active a").width()
```

Give it a shot, hope that's it!

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I thought that line was a bit dodgy. It's changed the behaviour slightly in IE but not got rid of the errors yet!

Comment: I'm thinking it's maybe to do with the `data` function, trying to find the documentation for it to see if there are any known issues with IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, seemed to be this line:

```
$magicLine
        .width($(".active a").width())
        .css("left", $(".active a").position().left);
```

Changed it to

```
$magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $(".active a").parent().position().left,
        //width: $magicLine.width($(".active a").width())
        width: $(".active a").width()
});
```

but this was being done in the `checkActive` function being called just before this line anyway so I just removed it....

Thanks for your help.